# Spring Crud Repository Custom left join query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I am developing Spring boot project with spring data jpa.

I have two entities with one to many relation.

Beds and Allocations

```
class Allocations(){
....

 @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="bedId" , nullable=true)
      private Beds beds;
.....
}

class Beds(){
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy="beds")
     @JsonIgnore
     private List<Allocations> allocations;
....
}
```

In Allocations repository when i do findAll() , i am able to get all the allocations with bedID.

But i want to find all the Beds which are not allocated .

Would like to perform left join on beds.

```
@Query("Select a from Beds b left join Allocations a on a.beds.bedID = b.bedId ")
    public List<Allocations> findtest();
```

How to perform the above activity .

Also i cant do findall() on beds as it will not give me the values of Allocations table.

Earlier i was using @jsonback/managedreferences annotation to find all the beds along with their allocations , But when i was adding a new allocations i was getting json managed reference errors  , so i used @Jsonignore annotation .

Please suggest the required solution

Answer (score 0):

I got the query to perform left join .

```
@Query("Select b , a from Beds b left join b.allocations a ")
```